# Problems to get the Id of an object passed by parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having trouble getting the Id of an object passed by parameter.

The code:

```
private void SetEntityState(TEntity entity, EntityState entityStated)
{
    var entry = this.Context.Entry(entity);

    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        // The problem is here.
        TEntity attachedEntity = this.DbSet.Where(
            x => x.Id.Equals(entity.Id)
            ).FirstOrDefault();

        if (attachedEntity != null)
        {
            var attachedEntry = this.Context.Entry(attachedEntity);

            attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);

            attachedEntry.State = entityStated;
        }
        else
        {
            entry.State = entityStated;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is here:

```
    TEntity attachedEntity = this.DbSet.Where(
        x => x.Id.Equals(entity.Id)
        ).FirstOrDefault();
```

The property 'Id' of the 'entity' is always returning 0 but in debbug, I can see that the value is 3.

Why is this happening?

Comment: why do you use x.Id.Equals(entity.ID) instead usual == ? Because I'm not sure that Equals method will be translated successfully to SQL by Entity Framework.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 TEntity attachedEntity = this.DbSet.Where(x => x.Id == entity.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

OR

```
Int32 entityId = entity.Id;
TEntity attachedEntity = this.DbSet.Where(x => x.Id == entityId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Check updated code .. I have tried with both way in my end, both are working fine

Comment: Hello I found the problem, I have a base model and a model that inherits this with the name of "Contact", I had to property "Id" in the two classes, then .NET was returning 0. I removed the "Id" property in class "Contact", keeping only the "Id" in the base model. But anyway, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try (for testing):

```
var entry = Context.Find(entity);
```

instead of

```
var entry = this.Context.Entry(entity);
```

Comment: Hi, "Find" not is a method of context. The context is a class inheriting of DbContext.